# Install OpenCV on Mac Catalina

Tags: java, opencv

I am trying to install OpenCV on my Mac using this tutorial: https://medium.com/macoclock/setting-up-mac-for-opencv-java-development-with-intellij-idea-fd2153eb634f

When I do:

> brew install opencv

I receive:

```
==> Searching for similarly named formulae... 
These similarly named formulae were found: 
opencv                     opencv@2               opencv@3 
To install one of them, run (for example):   
brew install opencv 
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "opencv".
==> Searching taps on GitHub... 
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

It displays "opencv" formula, so why it does not install it?
How to fix?

Also I have done:

```
> xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

and

```
> brew install ant
Warning: ant 1.10.9 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 1.10.9, run `brew reinstall ant`
```

when try

> brew install --build-from-source opencv

then receive the same error.

Also tried:

```
> brew uninstall opencv
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "opencv".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there's more to do with installing OpenCV via homebrew than `brew install opencv`.

You need to make sure you have XCode Command Line Tools installed, as well as ANT. Then you need to run

`brew install --build-from-source opencv`

Take a look at the [documentation](https://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/01-installing-opencv-for-java.html#install-opencv-3-x-under-macos) for details and specifics.

Also it might be a homebrew issue - so update brew and run doctor.

Comment: I have done all these - see my updated question - got the same effect

Comment: Did you update brew and run doctor to make sure it wasn't a homebrew issue? Do that first.

Comment: The right answer - run "brew doctor". It helped. After I fixed it all works. Add this to your text please. Thank you. Doctor gave: Warning: You have uncommitted modifications to Homebrew/homebrew-core.
If this is a surprise to you, then you should stash these modifications.
Stashing returns Homebrew to a pristine state but can be undone
should you later need to do so for some reason.
  "cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core && git stash && git clean -d -f"

Uncommitted files:
   M Formula/opencv.rb

Comment: @KirillCh Glad this worked out for you, and thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I found easier way to get OpenCV through Maven.

Add to pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openpnp/opencv -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0-3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

After adding the dependency, you need to load the library for use.  Normally, you would use the line:

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

however it will not work with this method. You need to change it to one of these lines:

```
nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadShared();
nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadLocally(); // Use in case loadShared() doesn't work
```

So the final result for test is:

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;

public class HelloCV {
    static {
        nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadShared();
        // nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadLocally(); // Use in case loadShared() doesn't work
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Core.VERSION);
        System.out.println(Core.VERSION_MAJOR);
        System.out.println(Core.VERSION_MINOR);
        System.out.println(Core.VERSION_REVISION);
        System.out.println(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        System.out.println(Core.getBuildInformation());
    }
}
```

Comment: Mac M1 is not supported